# Chrome browser doesn't clear PHP Session's due to its new feature "Continue where you left off"

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, session, session-cookies

In new update chorme added a feature "Continue where you left off" which keeps the logins and session with it even after closing the browser and when you reopen the browser it starts where you left. I've used PHP session in my project also I've cleared the session using

```
<?php
$time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$timeout_duration = 900;
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && 
   ($time - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) > $timeout_duration) {

    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = $time;

?>
```

But still chrome doesn't clear the session and I can easily get to the page where I left without even signing in.

****I WANT TO DESTROY ALL THE SESSION VALUES ONCE TAB IS CLOSED SO THAT WHEN ANY USER REOPENS THE BROWSER MUST HAVE TO LOGIN WITH USERNAME AND PASSWORD**** Please help.

*Session works fine on MOZILLA FIRE FOX

Comment: If you want to destroy all sessions, why are you defining `$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']` again at the end?

Comment: Hello, I tried removing it, but still not working

Comment: Did you try without `session_start();` too?